# Git commit pathspec error

Tags: git

I have a git repository where the following git commands work correctly:

1. `git commit -am 'update'`
2. `git commit -m 'update' ".openshift/themes/af2015/page.php"`

However, the command below does not work but results in an error:

```
git commit -m 'update' ".openshift/themes/af2015/images/cookbook/small/cookbook1.jpg"
```

The error message is:

```
error: pathspec '.openshift/themes/af2015/images/cookbook/small/cookbook1.jpg' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I get similar error messages for files in sub-directories of `.openshift/themes/af2015`.  I've read other posts where the issue was quotes (" vs '), and tried with " throughout, but that did not help. All the files are present:

```
> ls .openshift/themes/af2015/images/cookbook/small/cookbook1.jpg
.openshift/themes/af2015/images/cookbook/small/cookbook1.jpg
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: are the files added to the git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add .openshift/themes/af2015/images/cookbook/small/cookbook1.jpg`

`git add <another_file>`

`git add <even> <more> <files>`

`git commit`

*edit message in text editor with nice formatting*

Git will not recognize the files that are not tracked. Have you ran `git add` on the failing file before commiting?

Comment: I thing this may be solving it

Comment: @SimonH glad to know that. If it does solve your issue, please accept the answer ;) And I strongly suggest not using neither `-a` nor `-m` flags for git commit command unless it's an initial repository commit. Manually adding files improves your control over the changes and rules out the possibility of making mistakes like this. A good commit message will make you thank yourself in 6 months when you'll want to understand what were you doing and why :)

Comment: Actually this is ask being orchestrated by gulp-git which I think knocked me out of my normal workflow. About to board a plane but won't forget you